# Get xml from a php webservice url using android

Tags: android, xml, http-get

I want to read a xml from a service url, I wrote the code, my url is ok, seen from browser,

```
    public String getXML(){
    String line = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://localhost/simplewebservice/index.php?user=1");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("Error reading xml", ex.toString());
    }
    return line;
}
```

But it gives me the following error `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`.
Can anyone have a better solution for this?

Kind regards,

Pritom.

Comment: did U add Internet permission in manifest.xml

Comment: no, I am not added that, how can I do that???

Comment: I added that, now my error is `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that your using emulator.

Andriod emulator is separate virtual machine by itself. If we provide `localhost/127.0.0.1` as a hostname, then emulator will try to search url within its environment. To avoid this problem, we need to provide the ipaddress of local machine.

Pls note that machine name as a hostname will also give problem.

```
127.0.0.1 refers to localhost in the Emulator, not your machine.

Use 10.0.2.2 to connect to your host machine.
```

Comment: Can u please tell me how can I change my localhost ip address?

Comment: He is not saying change your localhost's IP address. He is saying use HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2/simplewebservice/index.php?user=1"); instead of HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://localhost/simplewebservice/index.php?user=1"); -- This will connect to your HOST computer (windows / linux / mac) instead of your emulator.

Comment: If you were running from tablet onto a local LAN to connect to a server would it be 192.168.1.2/index.php? 192.168.1.2 being the ip address of the server.

Answer (score 4):

in your manifest.xml add this description

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I added that, now my error is `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused`

Comment: because it doesn't work with localhost or 127.0.0.1 u should change ur local ip adress for exemple 124.0.1.1 or anything else!

Comment: or if you can paste your page (index.php) on internet it will work certainly!

Comment: How can I change my local ip address? I am now confused and dont get any suggestions from google.

Comment: do this and it will let you change/save your hosts file. 

1) Browse to Start -> All Programs -> Accessories 
2) Right click "Notepad" and select "Run as administrator" 
3) Click "Continue" on the UAC prompt 
4) Click File -> Open 
5) Browse to "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc" 
6) Change the file filter drop down box from "Text Documents (*.txt)" to "All Files (*.*)" 
7) Select "hosts" and click "Open" 
8) Make the needed changes and close Notepad. Save when prompted.