# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException while fetching image from web

Tags: android, rest, service, web

i get this error every time i want to display image from web using build in gallery in Android.

```
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://192.168.10.132:8000/someimage.jpg typ=image/* }
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at my.package.activities.MediaActivity$2.onItemClick(MediaActivity.java:58)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1936)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-03 10:12:59.895: E/AndroidRuntime(27974): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code is:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        Media clicked = adapter.getItem(position);

        String url = Backend.BASE_MEDIA_URL + clicked.url_big;

        Log.d("Media", url);

        Intent intent = new Intent();  
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "image/*");  
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
});
```

I am 100% positive that url is correct. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Manifest file, I removed some irrelevant activities

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.package" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >


        <activity android:name=".android.intent.action.VIEW" ></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have mention permission in your manifest file?

Comment: Which permission? I added activity .android.intent.action.VIEW to manifest but it didn't work.

Comment: can you open that URL in your browser  "http://192.168.10.132:8000/someimage.jpg"? I cant able to open it.

Comment: @pawelo Add your new activity like this <activity android:name=".YouActivity"></activity> within application tab.

Comment: I just noticed, that if i change `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "image/*");` to `intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));` system asks my how to handle this URI (e.g. with browser) and if i choose browser, it works. But i still want to use system gallery by default.

Comment: @pawello Try this way to start activity Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,YourNewActivity.class);   startActivity(intent);

Comment: @PadmaKumar it's local, works for me

Comment: Ru using emulator? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8680582/1012284

Comment: @Akshay adding to manifest didn't help. How to pass android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW as .class to Intent(Context, <?>.class)?

Comment: try in emulator it will work.

Comment: @pawelo Can you please post your menifest file?

Comment: @PadmaKumar same issue in emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i get this error every time i want to display image from web using build in gallery in Android

First, there is no single "build in gallery" application. There are hundreds upon hundreds of devices, and they will have a variety of "build in gallery" applications.

Second, there is nothing on your device capable of "display image from web", other than the browser, and then only if you let Android determine the actual concrete MIME type. There is no requirement that any device's "build in gallery" application support third-party apps using it to download and display images.

Comment: So, what do you suggest? Shall I build my own custom activity to display images? I need autorotate and multitouch resizing. What do you think is good practice to displaying full screen pictures with android?

Comment: @pawelo: "I need autorotate and multitouch resizing" -- then code that yourself. First, `ACTION_VIEW` is to view an image, not to edit an image. Second, there is no guarantee that a user will have an app that offers "autorotate and multitouch resizing" that you can ask to edit your image for you. If you wish to more generically allow the user to download and edit an image, download the image yourself, the use an `ACTION_EDIT` `Intent` with the correct MIME type... but this would allow the user to do any sort of editing, and only if they have an image editor installed.