# getting JSON response from localhost

Tags: json, localhost, response

I want to get JSON response from my localhost where I have created a .php file which is returning the JSON response.. It works well except for localhost. My apache server and myPhp server are working well. Could somebody assist me?

Comment: Give some more information on your problem. Elaborate a little bit.

Comment: Ok. I have created a class in android which is accepting an URL and converting the JSON response returned by the URL to string.. Finally the class displays the string ( i.e JSON response). It works well for all URL's. But if I want to do the same for the URL i.e. .php file stored on localhost it gives me an error org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused.. I am confused for this. If you want I can put my code here

Comment: Which port you are trying to connect to ?

Comment: which OS are you using for development linux or windows ?

Comment: Ok the first thing I would suggest you is to check if the port is free and not used by any other process and i don't know how to do that on mac. The second is you try to change the localhost IP and Port on from which your program is interacting.

Comment: local (machine) host in Android Emulator can be accessed by the IP 10.0.2.2

Comment: This will also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680457/get-xml-from-a-php-webservice-url-using-android

Comment: Yeah.. It worked very well for IP address 10.0.2.2  You were right. The Emulator was trying to search localhost within its environment. Thank you very much